# Creating CNAME to delegated domain

Tags: cname-record, delegation, f5-big-ip, windows-dns

We are trying to configure F5 to do load balancing on 4 sub domains similar to [this article](http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/0000/200/sol277.html).

For Example

```
prod.wip.example.com.  NS   F5NS1.example.com.  
prod.wip.example.com.  NS   F5NS2.example.com. 
test.wip.example.com.  NS   F5NS1.example.com. 
test.wip.example.com.  NS   F5NS2.example.com.
```

Then we want to make CNAMEs instead of delegating individual sub-domains, e.g.

```
myapp.example.com CNAME prod.wip.example.com
```

Microsoft DNS gives an error when I attempt to make the CNAME.

```
dnscmd ns1 /recordadd example.com myapp CNAME myapp.prod.wip.example.com.
Command failed:  DNS_ERROR_NOT_ALLOWED_UNDER_DELEGATION     9563  (0000255b)
```

The error makes perfect sense, but does anyone know of a way around it? Or are my NS records incorrect for this setup?

Answer (score 2):

What you showed in:

> myapp.example.com CNAME prod.wip.example.com

Is different of:

> dnscmd ns1 /recordadd example.com myapp CNAME myapp.prod.wip.example.com.

Do you want myapp.example.com to point to prod.wip.example.com or myapp.prod.wip.example.com?

In both case if myapp.example.com is another zone than example.com you must type:

> dnscmd ns1 /recordadd myapp.example.com myapp CNAME myapp.prod.wip.example.com.

Answer (score -1):

You should try it in the gui first and see if it still errors out.

If it does not, then it is your command line that is the problem.